# Javascript multi range sliders value cross-update

Tags: javascript, slider

Need a javascript listener or function 'frame' to fill with some final calculations. The plan is for an online calculator that will take 3 values from range sliders and update 5-6 output only fields. Point is, that once we update each of the sliders, the other two must update too (acc to calc I got).

I've got the whole calc working in PHP, but in that solution there was always only one of these 3 inputs given and rest got calculated. Not posting whole script as the calculations are pretty complex.

Perhaps you can help me with the simplest listeners set for these 3 range sliders that I could just fill in with calculations.
The simplest js possible, no libraries are necessary.

Thanks

```
<div id="slidercontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" step="50" class="slider" id="mfee">
  <p>Mfee value: <span id="mfeeval">0.00</span></p>
  
  <input type="range" min="0" max="30000" value="1000" step="100" class="slider" id="usage">
  <p>Usage value: <span id="usageval">0.00</span></p>

  <input type="range" min="0" max="30.61" value="5" class="slider" id="power">
  <p>Power value: <span id="powerval">0.00</span></p>
  
  <ul>  
   <li>Result #1 <span id="r1">0.00</span></li>
   <li>Result #2 <span id="r2">0.00</span></li>
   <li>Result #3 <span id="r3">0.00</span></li>
   <li>Result #4 <span id="r4">0.00</span></li>
   <li>Result #1 <span id="45">0.00</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So I guess I'd need to have a listener added to each of three sliders that on value change will update all  vlue ids and other sliders, too...

Got maths to calculate all result fields, just don't know how to make working listeners that will trigger on sliders change

Looking forward to your help
thank you

Comment: Can you tell how should each slider change with respect to others

Comment: The calculations are secondary, my main problem was to wrap up their crossupdating at all.
In the meantime I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050749/dynamically-change-range-slider-value-when-different-range-slider-is-moved and used as a base, expanding it to 3 uses, not two. I also used the oninput trigger instead of onchange, so adjustments are made 'live' while scrolling.
Yet - maybe there's more elegant solution to it all, not by three separate functions.
On the other hand - the simplest solutions work best ;)